# SpatialLite for Android NDK Geos Configure Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, geospatial, geos, spatialite

I'm trying to build the following project for Android:

http://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/

Does anyone know why there may be errors when running ndk-build for LineIntersector.cpp?

```
jni/geos-3.2.2/source/algorithm/LineIntersector.cpp:223: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
```

I'm running try to compile this on a mac and I'm an NDK newbie. Here is my configure that I run in the geos root

```
./configure --build=i686-android-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-eabi
```

The error appears to be with the ISNAN function

Comment: Created an issue to track problem.  https://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/issues/detail?id=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can only build on Ubuntu.  The step where you run `./configure` is the issue on other platforms.  I have posted the latest binaries in the download section.  You could open the apk and copy the .so files.

I was able to get geos to build on my Mac by editing /source/headers/geos/platform.h

```
/* Set to 1 if you have `int64_t' type */
/* #undef HAVE_INT64_T_64 */

/* Set to 1 if `long int' is 64 bits */
/* #undef HAVE_LONG_INT_64 */

/* Set to 1 if `long long int' is 64 bits */
/* #undef HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 */

/* Set to 1 if you have ieeefp.h */
/* #undef HAVE_IEEEFP_H */

/* Has finite */
#define HAVE_FINITE 1

/* Has isfinite */
/* #undef HAVE_ISFINITE */

/* Has isnan */
#define HAVE_ISNAN 1
```

Comment: This must be done after running the ./configure. After modifying platform.h, running the ndk-build works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've build this project successfully on Win7,cygwin environment, have a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/issues/detail?id=3